# replaceAll Not Working Properly with String

Tags: java, regex, ng-options

I got unexpected result...

```
 String s1 = "all"; 
 System.out.println(s1.replaceAll("$", "#"));
```

i.e not replacing, if there is no $ then no need to replace but why JVM added '#'.
o/p: all#

Comment: Y U NO READ THE JAVADOC?

Answer (score 5):

`replaceAll` takes a regular expression as its first argument where `$` matches the end of the input String. You need to escape the character to match it literally

```
System.out.println("all".replaceAll("\\$", "#"));
```

or simply use

```
System.out.println("all".replace("$", "#"));
```

Comment: So you would have to escape it, i.e `\$`?